# Maximum Number of Entries in Crontab

Tags: cron

If it exists, what is the maximum number of cron jobs (entries?) that can be added to a server's crontab? How do I tell? I'm on RHEL 6.

I googled around, but did not see a conclusive answer -- some were 256, some 65K, some said limitless.

Comment: Checkout this related answer on http://serverfault.com/questions/85341/crontab-size-limit

Comment: Thank you, that was one of the pages I found in my search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question you should have a look at the cron implementation for your distribution. RHEL seems to use cronie - you can find the [source code for cronie online](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=cronie.git).

cronies limit seems to depend on the filesystem (maximum file size) as the cron daemon stores the crontab entries per user in a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) - see [user.c from cronie for details](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=cronie.git;a=blob;f=src/user.c#l109). This means the maximum number of job entries for crontab is basically unlimited.

Comment: Thank you. So, does "linked list" imply "unlimited"  ... ? until all the memory is taken up ... ?

Comment: @KM01 not necessarily as you still can implement/enforce limits but typically yes linked list often means unlimited size. The linked source code shows no restrictions re. the number of entries. And it would take a **lot** of entries to fill the memory with crontab entries.